# Mapping Amazon S3 to a Directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-s3

In my htaccess file, I have:

```
RewriteRule ^(images/.*)$ http://static.example.com/$1 [P]
```

And that works as a redirect. I have a S3 bucket mapped to static.example.com. However, if you visit something in images/ it redirects to the static.example.com full URL. Is there a way to do this while masking the static.example.com url? So basically, any references to /images stay at /images and not static.?

Comment: Have you looked at [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)?

Comment: `P` flag is for proxy, but it won't work unless you have mod_proxy loaded.

Comment: Aha! I wondered about that [P]. It seems like this is unlikely to ever work in a shared host. Thank you both for the input there.